# WhitelabelError Page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

While  I am doing simple spring boot application that showing a message in jsp page, I am getting the white label error page, what can be the reason?

in my application.java page:

```
package net.aswathy.springboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootWebAppJspApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootWebAppJspApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

appplication properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

in my controller:

```
package net.aswathy.springboot;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class scontroller {
     @GetMapping("/welcome")
     public String welcome(Model model) {
           model.addAttribute("message","Helloworld..!");
           return "welcome";
}
}
```

in my jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${message}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: everything looks fine, maybe it can be cache problems, can you do `hard reset reload` with your web browser ? also, maybe you missed something, can you check this example also ? https://github.com/mamadaliev/spring-boot-jsp-postgres

Comment: You sure your jsp page is inside `/WEB-INF/views/?
`